# Firebase security rules to force oneTo many relationship?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Let's say I have a structure of movies by categories I define 3 Nodes:

```
Film
    filmId1
        Tiltle = "xxx"
        type :  IdAction
    filmId2
        Tiltle = "yyy"
        type = Idcomedy

Type
    IdAction
        descrition = "action movie"
    IdComedy
        descrition ="funy"
    IdClassic
        Descrition = "old movies"

MoviesByType
    IdAction
        filmId1: true
        filmI10 : true
```

**How can I create a firebase security rule to validate from server side that when a client create a new Film entry it also create the corresponding MoviesByType relation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you can enforce this with a security rule.  However, you can enforce it by using a Firebase database trigger.

You can create a trigger that fires when the client writes data to the "Film" node.  The trigger can automatically make the proper updates to the "MoviesByType" node.  The client only needs to perform one write, and the server takes care of keeping itself up to date via the trigger.

[Here is the documentation on Firebase triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).